# I keep getting 23750 as a password with a post submission

Tags: php, mysql

I am completely stumped here.  I am creating a simple member system for class and I keep getting "23750" no matter what password variation I type in.  First I thought it was a db issue, so I manually entered one and it was fine.  Then, i echoed out the password to the next page and I am getting 23750 still.  I made the form again from scratch, and the number 23750 does not even remotely exist in any of my code.  Any thoughts?  Here is the code, anyways.

```
<?php 
// Check if user is logged in first
if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) { // user is logged in
    header("Location: members.php");
}
$pageTitle = 'Register';
require('includes/header.php'); ?>
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Register</h3>
            <?php

        // Check if form has been submitted
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // user submitted the form
            // Validate info
            // Grab variables
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
            $fname = $_POST['fname'];
            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            $age = $_POST['age'];
            $address = $_POST['address'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
            $pass_hint = $_POST['pass_hint'];

            // Check if form was completely filled out
            if ($email != "") { // email was filled out
                if ($email2) { // verify email was filled out
                    if ($fname) { // first name was filled out
                        if ($lname) { // last name was filled out
                            if ($gender != 'select') { // gender was filled out
                                if ($age) { // age was filled out
                                    if ($password) { // password was filled out
                                        if ($password2) { // verification password was filled out
                                            if (strlen($password) > 7) { // password is less than 8 characters}
                                                if ($pass_hint) { // password hint was filled out
                                                    if ($password !== $pass_hint) { // password hint does not equal password
                                                    // All information was entered
                                                    // Check if email and password match each other
                                                        if ($email === $email2) { // emails match
                                                            if ($password === $password2) { // passwords match
                                                                // all form data is good, now check with database
                                                                require('includes/database.php'); // Connect to databae
                                                                // Check if email exists
                                                                $qry = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
                                                                $qry->execute();

                                                                // Count rows
                                                                $count = $qry->rowCount();
                                                                if ($count != 1) { // email does not exist
                                                                    // All information is good, insert to database
                                                                    // Query database
                                                                    $qry = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, fname, lname, gender, age, password, pass_hint) VALUES ('$email', '$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$age', '$password', '$pass_hint');");
                                                                    $qry->execute();

                                                                    // Check if it was submitted successfully
                                                                    $count = $qry->rowCount();
                                                                    if ($count == 1) { // submitted successfully
                                                                        echo $password;
                                                                        echo 'You have been successfully registered, now forwarding you to the login page...';
                                                                        ?> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='login.php'" /> <?php
                                                                    } else { // error submitting info
                                                                        echo 'There was a system error, please contact the administrator';
                                                                        registration_form();
                                                                    }
                                                                } else { // email does exist
                                                                    echo 'A user with that email already exists!';
                                                                    registration_form();
                                                                }
                                                            } else { // passwords do not match
                                                                echo 'Your passwords must match!';
                                                                registration_form();
                                                            }
                                                        } else { // emails do not match
                                                            echo 'Your emails must match!';
                                                            registration_form();
                                                        }
                                                    } else { // password hint matches password given
                                                        echo 'Your password hint cannot equal your password!';
                                                        registration_form();
                                                    }
                                                } else { // password hint was not filled out
                                                    echo 'Please enter a password hint';
                                                    registration_form();
                                                }
                                            } else { // password is not 8 characters or longer
                                                echo 'Your password must be 8 characters of longer';
                                                registration_form();
                                            }
                                        } else { // verification password was not filled out
                                            echo 'Please enter your password twice!';
                                            registration_form();
                                        }
                                    } else { // password aws not filled out
                                        echo 'Please enter a password';
                                        registration_form();
                                    }
                                } else { // age was not filled out
                                    echo 'Please enter your age';
                                    registration_form();
                                }
                            } else { // gender was not filled out
                                echo 'Please select a gender';
                                registration_form();
                            }
                        } else { // last name was not filled out
                            echo 'Please enter your last name';
                            registration_form();
                        }
                    } else { // first name was not filled out
                        echo 'Please enter your first name';
                        registration_form();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Please enter your cerification email';
                    registration_form();
                }
            } else { // email was not filled out
                echo "Please enter your email address!";
                registration_form();
            }


        } else { // user did not submit form, show reg form
            echo "  <form action='register.php' method='post'>
                            <p>email <input type='text' name='email'></p>
                            <p>confirm email <input type='text' name='email2'></p>
                            <p>first name <input type='text' name='fname'></p>
                            <p>last name <input type='text' name='lname'></p>
                            <select id='gender' name='gender'>
                                    <option value='1'>Male</option>
                                    <option value='2'>Female</option>
                            </select>
                            <p>age <input type='text' name='age'></p>
                            <p>address <input type='text' name='address'></p>
                            <p>password <input type='password' name='password'></p>
                            <p>confirm pass <input type='password' name='password'></p>
                            <p>hint <input type='text' name='pass_hint'></p>
                            <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></p>
                    </form>";
        }

        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That nested if statement is a huge mess. That's an obvious bad code smell and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Is your password an int field in your database, instead of a string?

Comment: @JohnConde What would you recommend doing for a registration form that needs to verify all of this?

Comment: No Jessica, it is a varchar.

Comment: For whatever reason, I changed the password variable from $password to $password1 and it works.  I'm curious about how to verify this info in a cleaner fashion though, if you don't mind John.  Thanks.

Comment: For something cleaner, you may consider using a library or framework, if your project is big enough to justify doing so. Check out this validation in the CakePHP framework:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Comment: @user3010455 - you could also check each field one by one, and add any error messages into an array; if the array is empty at the end, you can go ahead and create the new user; otherwise, you can display the array in whatever format you want.

Comment: easy fix for the nested if is to 1) stop the form from submitting unless the inputs are correctly and not empty using javascript and 2) put all of the if statements into one if statement since if the form was submitted correctly then any form submission that is incorrect would be submitted by a hacker and then disregard the input. and display error message and possibly block IP address

Comment: Yeah cause only hackers ever use the web without javascript enabled! (not).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains a typo (commented by OP)

Answer (score 0):

At least 2 issues with your code not related but:

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
```

Add an isset() also

```
<p>password <input type='password' name='password'></p>
<p>confirm pass <input type='password' name='password'></p>
```

You don't have the password2 here.

And on my side, with removing the mysql logic and add bypass, I have the password I entered in the form.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer, but it needs space, so feel free to vote down.)

To 'fix' the nested code:

```
$error = true;

if ( !$email ) {
  echo 'Invalid e-mail!';
  registration_form();
}

else if ( !$email2 ) {
  echo 'Invalid e-mail 2!';
  registration_form();
}

else if ( !$fname ) {
  echo 'Invalid first name!';
  registration_form();
}

else if ( !$lname ) {
  echo 'Invalid last name!';
  registration_form();
}

else {
  $error = false;
}

if ( !$error ) {
  // Yeeeeh. Do register stuff?
}
```

It's still messy, but less so. For you too.